# What to look out for when designing mixed material enclosure?

Tags: design, distortion, loudspeakers, custom, concrete

I have a (presumably naive) idea to make the front of the enclosure out of concrete. The loudspeaker itself would a sealed bookshelf type with a tweeter and a 5" woofer.

I'm considering these options but not sure which one is the best compromise:

- Option A: Abandon my dreams and make the whole thing with MDF or plywood.
- Option B: Go crazy and make a pretty enclosure with 4cm thick concrete front side and 1cm thick bamboo on other sides. I have a high concern that this is really stupid in terms of resonance, but would be the prettiest - subjectively.
- Option C: Have the 4cm thick front panel paired with similar thickness mdf or plywood on other sides.

Comment: I'll keep this question up to date with my progress as I learn more, seems like this is not a super popular one :P
I've found out that ideally the enclosure of a loudspeaker should not vibrate, so if the walls are made of a flexible material it's advised to be thicker while more solid (e.g stone, concrete) materials can be thinner. [This article](https://www.loudspeakerbuilding.com/Practical-guide/Cabinet-materials/10101,en) recommends at around 1.5 cm thick walls for loudspeakers that have a similar volume to mine (~8 liters) if the walls are made of wood.